# Implement Listeners in View Pager

Tags: android

Hi I'm making an app with a ViewPager using this tutorial http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-user-interface-design-horizontal-view-paging and the cool  thing about the ViewPager used here is that every page has a different layout based on xml. Problem is I've tried different ways of making the buttons I create in the layout to work but I cant quite find a place to put the onClick listeners. Here's the Adapter for the ViewPager:

```
class UniversePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

protected static final String[] CONTENT = new String[] { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", };

public int getCount() {
    return 4;
}

Dashboard activity;
public UniversePagerAdapter(Dashboard activity){
    this.activity = activity;
}

public Object instantiateItem(final View collection, int position) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    int resId = 0;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        resId = R.layout.one;
        break;
    case 1:
        resId = R.layout.two;
        break;
    case 2:
        resId = R.layout.three;
        break;
    case 3:
        resId = R.layout.four;
        break;
    }
    View view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);
    return view;
}



@Override
public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
    ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
    return arg0 == ((View) arg1);
}

@Override
public Parcelable saveState() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
  return UniversePagerAdapter.CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length];
}
}
```

And here's the part where it's bound:

```
public class Dashboard extends BaseActivity implements OnClickListener {

Button bNewButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dashboard);

    setAdapter();

}

public void initPagerView(int position, View view) {

    bNewButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bNewUniverse);
    bNewButton.setOnClickListener(this);

}

private void setAdapter() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mAdapter = new UniversePagerAdapter(Dashboard.this);

    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mPager.setCurrentItem(1);

    mIndicator = (TitlePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    mIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);
}                   

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "It Lives!!!!",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

The problem I have is initializing and using objects created in the xml layouts, since they're all in the Adapter.
Please help me out?

Comment: Testing answers and will give feedback soon :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can have function called initPagerView in your activity as following:

```
public void initPagerView(int position,View view){
   //Here you can use view.findViewById();
}
```

And in adapter:

```
private class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    public int getCount() {
        return 5;
    }
    <YourActivityClass> activity;
    public MyPagerAdapter(<YourActivityClass> activity){
        this.activity=activity;
    }
    public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        int resId = 0;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            resId = R.layout.farleft;
            break;
        case 1:
            resId = R.layout.left;
            break;
        case 2:
            resId = R.layout.middle;
            break;
        case 3:
            resId = R.layout.right;
            break;
        case 4:
            resId = R.layout.farright;
            break;
        }
        View view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);
        activity.initPagerView(position,view);
        return view;
    }
    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
        ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
        return arg0 == ((View) arg1);
    }
    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This is one way to do it.
Now in `initPagerView(int position,View view)` which is in your activity you can initialize your views which are added in view pager from adapter.

You can also create an `Interface` like:

```
public Interface PagerViewInitialiser{
   public initPagerView(int position,View view);
}
```

and make your activity implement this.

And in your pager adapter:

```
PagerViewInitialiser activity;
public MyPagerAdapter(PagerViewInitialiser  activity){
    this.activity=activity;
}
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for taking long. I've added the method to initializie the views but nothing is happening on click. I've updated the code to inculide the init...need help

Comment: you need to call activity.initPagerView(position,view); this in instantiateItem just before you return a view

Comment: Ive called init pagerView but get a null pointer exception when I add a listener to a button

Comment: The code is exactly as it is in the question...only that ive added the call. I'm initialising the button in initpagerview..thats where I add on click listener

Comment: The initpagetviewer is in my activity. And I call it in the adapter before returning a view. But if I initialise a button with view.findview....then say button.setonclick
...I get a null pointer

Comment: Solved it. In the initviewerpager simply switch-case the position. THANKYOU

Answer (score 0):

If you have buttons in your layout, after inflating the view in `instantiateItem`, you can 
call `findViewById` on the view you just inflated to obtain your buttons. Something like :

```
Button btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.yourBtn);
btn.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

One of approaches is:

Make your custom view that extends ViewGroup(RelativeLayout,LinearLayout...) for every custom page.
Pass context to your class that extend View

```
public class TestView extends RelativeLayout{


public enum Action{
   ACTION_TEST_BTN,
   ACTION_SOMETHING_ELSE
}

public interface MyTestViewActionListener{
      public void onAction(Action myAction);
}


private MyTestViewActionListener listener;

public TestView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mInflater.inflate(R.layout.left, this, true);
  }
public void setListener(MyTestViewActionListener listener){

   this.listener = listener;    

   Button btnTest = (Button)findViewById(this,R.id.btnTest);
   btnTest.setOnClickListener(
                new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                                                listener.onAction(Action.ACTION_TEST_BTN);

                    }
                });
}
.
.
.
}
```

Next you can in your PageAdapter:

```
TestView testV = new TestView(activity);
testV.setListener(listener);
```

Define constructor that look like this one

```
public MyPagerAdapter(<YourActivityClass> activity, MyTestViewActionListener listener){
        this.activity = activity;
        this.listener = listener;
    }
```

At the end you can in your activity/fragment implement interface MyTestViewActionListener and
implement method:

```
onAction(Action action)
{
  switch(action)
   case(Action.ACTION_TEST_BTN):
    //do something
   break;
  .
  .
}
```

Comment: Where do I put the TestView testV = new TestView(activity);
 testV.setListener(listener);...it's currently in the adapter..but when I click the but nothing happens